# Selected class not found when adding customized chart in tibco jasperreport 6.10.0

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am creating barchart in tibco jasper report 6.10.0, and I want to add some customization on the chart. After searching about solution, I have been found that the solution is to create external defined class with jfreechart library and import it to the jasper report. After creating the class and building the jar file, I added it in report and selected the class from chart customizer in report "the selected class not found" message appeared

[image: when adding the class]

When previewing the report:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not create chart customizer instance.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.createAndInitCustomizer(JRFillChart.java:353)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.<init>(JRFillChart.java:306)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.visitChart(JRFillObjectFactory.java:704)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseChart.visit(JRBaseChart.java:578)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractObjectFactory.getVisitResult(JRAbstractObjectFactory.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementGroup.<init>(JRFillElementGroup.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.<init>(JRFillElementContainer.java:95)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.<init>(JRFillBand.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getBand(JRFillObjectFactory.java:524)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.createFillBand(JRBaseFiller.java:366)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:284)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:79)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.<init>(BaseFillHandle.java:86)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.<init>(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:120)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.createHandle(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:244)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jaspersoft.bizdev.PieLabels cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.10.0.final
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:191)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:131)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.createAndInitCustomizer(JRFillChart.java:347)
... 18 more
```

[image]